# Get the filename of a running batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, filenames

I am trying to make a batch file that will write the name we names it.
For example if i names the file "test1" and start it it will change the title only to "test1" If i change the name to "bat file" it will display "bat file" in the title.

Is it possible to make a file that will write to a .txt file with the same name as the bat file? I am trying to make a batch file that will log sometings and write it too ".txt" where  is the name of the bat file without extension

Answer (score 4):

In batch files `%0` stores a reference to the current batch file. The exact format of the value depends on how the file is invoked, but there are a serie of modifiers that can be used to retrieve the needed information (You can see the documentation or execute `for /?`, as the help for this command also includes the full list of modifiers)

```dos
@echo off
    title %~n0
    echo I am %~n0
    > "%~dpn0.txt" echo This goes to the file
```

Where

```
%~n0 = name of the current batch file (without extension)
%~dpn0 = drive, path and file name (without extension) of the current batch file
```

Answer (score 0):

echo %~f0 for writing your batch file name. Use ">" to write anything to a file. For eg use echo "write this" > file.txt